# In Dark Mode, highlighted Winter Bash announcements have the wrong color

Tags: bug, winter-bash, dark-mode, winter-bash-2020

With dark mode enabled, all highlighted Winter Bash notifications in the Winter Bash menu have the wrong background color:

[image: the highlighting bug]

This applies to all new notifications, but it is especially noticeable on the perma-highlighted Hat Dash notification ([reported by Glorfindel on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357921/388442)).

Comment: I think that is an on purpose joke as it knows you switched to dark theme

Comment: "You've earned the right to post a bug report on Meta, thus [probably] earning you another hat!"

Comment: In related news, I cannot get the highlighting of this announcement to go away. It disappears when I acknowledge it, but comes right back when I refresh. (Edit: [Already reported by Glorfindel on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357921/1-new-hat-notification-doesnt-go-away).)

Comment: @CodyGray yes, a bit annoying because each time you think you have earned a secret hat ...

Comment: Surprinsingly, it's the same color as the highlighting in Late Answers.